# Iterating List of List in java8

Tags: java-8

I was wondering, How can we iterate a multilevel list using stream API in Java 8

For example,

```
List<List<String>> multiList = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> names= Arrays.asList("a","b");
List<String> fewMoreNames= Arrays.asList("e","f");
multiList.add(names);
multiList.add(fewMoreNames);
```

As per Java 8, I should go something like below

```
multiList.stream().... ?
```

I wanted to do this fluently(using internal iteration).Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this iteration? It hard to answer without knowing that.

Comment: I was wondering if it is possible or not using internal java8 iterators and streams. List of List can be a very common data structure in any programming solution.This question is generated from curosity:)

Comment: Of course it's possible, but there are many ways streams can be used for many purposes, so you'll have to ask a more specific question to get an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Got it folks, it was easy one. I was not looking at the API closely.
One of the solution is

`multiList .stream().forEach((x) -> x.stream().forEach(System.out::println));`

Comment: The preferred way is `multiList .stream().flatMap(List::stream).forEach(System.out::println);` as it’s one operation rather than multiple nested operations. You may notice the difference as soon as you want to perform a different action than `forEach`.